# Difference between "with a view to giving..." and "with a view to give..."

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement

Which one of the following is correct? And why?

> He teaches his students with a view to **giving** the light of education

> He teaches his students with a view to **give** the light of education

Edit: Added full sentence.

Comment: Is this marketing material? Giving us a whole sentence might help.

Comment: Either could be correct but since these aren't complete sentences, it's difficult to know which is more appropriate.

Comment: @YosefBaskin It is not a marketing material. Well, the full sentence is `He teaches his students with a view to giving/give the light of education.`

Comment: Please give us a whole sentence and context. For both those phrases I can invent both incorrect and correct sentences that contain them.

Comment: @DJClayworth I added the whole sentence. Could you tell now which one is more appropriate?

Comment: Could be a translation issue, applying what sounds good in the origianl to the other. *Giving* is a bit better here, but both say he teaches for the same of educating, which in English is tautology, not poetry.

Comment: *With a view to* + gerund is a fixed construction: *...with a view to giving.* The preposition *to* is followed by its object — here, the gerund *giving*, which functions like a noun.

Comment: Does he teach students that don't have a view to [give/giving]? It's a badly worded sentence, regardless of the give/giving issue (which comes down to preference or opinion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those cases where usage has changed over time. Today, the construction ***with a view to...*** is almost always followed by a ***gerund / continuous*** noun form, but a couple of centuries it was more often followed by an infinitive ("bare, unmarked", without the infinitive marker ***to***). [For example...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with%20a%20view%20to%20making%2Cwith%20a%20view%20to%20make&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20a%20view%20to%20making%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20a%20view%20to%20make%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwith%20a%20view%20to%20making%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20a%20view%20to%20make%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

So don't be too surprised if you encounter *with a view to **give*** (particularly in older texts), but stick to *with a view to **giving*** if you use the idiom yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your deep explantion.

Comment: I dislike usage answers without other evidence. There are cases where the infinitive would be used correctly today.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I don't understand what you mean. Are you suggesting that *the exact context makes a difference*, and that there are some contexts where only the infinitive is "correct", and *other* contexts where only the continuous is correct? I don't think I believe that, but I'm open to persuasion.